# prove the greedy algorithm for Gas Station is valid

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, greedy, proof

I'm trying to prove the [solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJwbPZGo05A) for the problem [Gas Station (LeetCode 134)](https://leetcode.com/problems/gas-station/)

Let's define `d_i` to be the difference `g_i - c_i`.

Basically it's a greedy solution where you look for the first `k` s.t.

`\sum_{i=k}^n d_i >= 0`

Let's denote the following:

`A = \sum_{i=1}^k d_i`

`B = \sum_{i=k+1}^n d_i`

Notice that by definition of `k`, `A<0` and `B >= 0`.

Since we know that there's a unique solution:

`A+B >= 0 --> B >= -A`

We want to show that `B-A >= 0`. This will show that we have enough gas for `A` after finishing the `B` part.

So `B-A >= B+B >= 0`

Is my proof correct?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! You should note that readers usually prefer self-contained questions. Personally I have no intention of watching that youtube video you linked. So, even if I wanted to answer, I couldn't. Have a good day!

Comment: You should always post complete description.  For this question, you can re-watch the same video, pay attention at/around 10 minutes~   again.

Comment: I have failed to understand few points related to your proof. *Is there any room we can discuss that?* I do not think comment will be a good place for it.